# share same controller among all the templates in an ionic tab

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

[image]

> From the above image ,
> for example the pages inside TAB3, `page2.html` , `page3.html` , ... should share same controller in a way that updates to the data inside the controller in page2 should pass to page3 and so on . 
>   ....
>   I tried a bunch of stuffs .
>    ....
>   After that I solved it partially by specifying the controller like below,specifying the controller in the `ion-tab`.

```
  <ion-tab ng-controller="MyCtrl" href="#/tab/about">
  <ion-nav-view name="tab-about"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
```

Is there any other better way than this ,Because one problem that I experienced due to this approach is "the `MyCtrl` get executed before executing the `run`".Note:There will be different controllers for each tabs.

> I tried my best to recreate my issue in a codepen,http://codepen.io/keephacking/pen/ZOwwdN?editors=1010
>   (In Codepen)I want the second view inside `Home` tab to inherit the `$scope.name` variable of `HomeCtrl`.
>   Thanks.

Comment: What's the reason for having the same controller? Do you want to share data throughout different views?

Comment: not only that , the  functions related to all the templates inside a tab will be in one controller  and these templates are  sequential in a way one depend on other .

Comment: You can bind a controller function to each view when defining the routes/states which ensures having all the functions in all views of the same controller. However, those is not the same controller since it is instantiated separately for each view. Due to that you can share all the functions but not the data. For sharing data I suggest using a service as shown here: http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-tutorial-9-passing-data-between-pages/

Comment: @albert . There will be performance issue with that approach in my case,.The controller will be fetching datas needed for each views and storing in the local database , each view cause a new instance of the controller to load.

Comment: If you're required to use the same controller for sibling views (non parent-child relation) then your design is flawed. You should use **Services** in order to share data between views. Also your last statement is false because ionic loads each controller & template once (unless specified explicitly).

Comment: @MuliYulzary, Whats the last false statement ? you mean "each view cause a new instance of the controller to load"

Comment: Yes. that's what I meant. Ionic uses cache to store controller instances and templates.

Comment: yep exactly thats what I meant. When the app starts, different instances of the same controller will be created (in my case .ie., using same controller for each templates in a tab) .